# How to tell the animation in Chrome browser is not in motion?

Tags: java, selenium

Clicking an element always ended up failure. Just found the reason is that the element is not ready to click because it comes with some shaking animation even if Explicit wait method `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ele)` is implemented.
In debugging mode, I can click. Of course. But in run mode, no difference.

`ElementClickInterceptedException` This is the exception.

Any idea to tell that animation finished and actually ready to be clicked?

[image]

Comment: Unable to give you guys the site as it is private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to "hard-click" on the element via JavaScript:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("Element's ID Goes Here"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Hi Tal, This script works for me and no issue. However, is there any way to determine the element is clickable or CSS animation is finished? I test cross browser test that Chrome webdriver cannot click the element what Firefox does. Thank you Tal.

Comment: @deokyongsong There must be a way to do this, I just don't know how. Chrome and Firefox act different in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

If Tal Angel's answer doesn't work for you, try using the Actions class to move to the element's position and force a click event.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(ele).click().build().perform();
```

You will need to import **org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;** to do this.

[Runnable example here](https://mx1.maxtaf.com/cases/3e02ed92-e0c7-471a-b16a-4af6ac5d2205?projectId=bugtestproject2)

Comment: Hi @MDelic. This script doesn't work. The moment `perform()` is not ready to click already.

Comment: Ah fair enough. I'm glad you could find the answer in Tal Angel's answer. Just for my own knowledge can you elaborate on what you mean by "The moment perform() is not ready to click already."? Are you saying that the webdriver is not able to click on your element?

Comment: Yes I am saying that. It won't be able to click the element by using perform(). My question is how to tell the page I test is ready to click as the page pops up with some shaking animation which disturbing click on it and it gives an Exception as abovementioned.

Comment: Anyway, clicking the element with Javascript Executor can click what WebDriver cannot sometimes.